# GtkExpander style widget in wxWidgets?

Tags: python, windows, gtk, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm looking for a widget along the lines of [GtkExpander](http://gtk.php.net/manual/en/images/reference/gtk/gtkexpander.png), but for wxWidgets. Can't seem to find anything obvious in the documentation. Custom widgets (non-GPL) from somewhere else would be fine, but they need to work on Windows (i.e. without GTK).

Practically (if it makes any difference) this is primarily for wxPython, on Windows and hopefully Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Damn, I'm stupid. If you've got here because you're stupid too, check out [wxCollapsiblePane](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_collapsible_pane.html).